# Can you write a function in VBA that displays values in cells other than then cell the function is in?

Tags: vba, excel, foreach

I am trying to write something like: If the value "O" is found in this range (M3:Q3) then fill all the cells in the range (M3:Q3) not containing the "O" with "X". 
Here is what I have so far. I have had a lot of trouble getting the function to populate a value in anything other than the cell the function is being called.

```
Function positive(range_data As range)
Dim display As String
    display = ""
Dim positiveValue As Boolean


For Each Item In range_data
    If Item.Value = "O" Then
       positiveValue = True
    End If
Next
If positiveValue = True Then
    For Each Item In range_data
        If Item.Value = "" Then
             Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Item.row, Item.Column).Value = "X"
        End If
    Next
End If
'positive = range_data
'positive = display
End Function
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I believe there is a workaround, but easier to use a sub.

Comment: To elaborate, see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/170787/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel

Comment: What is the problem that you are actually getting? it seemed to work for me

Comment: The problem I am trying to solve is I have a range of 5 cells in one row, if somewhere in those 5 cells there is the value of "O", then I want to fill in every other cell in that range with "X" but leave the "O". for instance if I have: |_|_|O|_|_|, then I want to have logic that will update the range to |X|X|O|X|X|. The code I have above isnt doing that for me. it will value the cell I have the formula in with "X" if there is a "O" in the range, but thats not what I want. i want it to put "X" value in the blank spaces of the range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code seems to work fine, I just turned it into a Sub

```
Sub positive(range_data As Range)
  Dim display As String
    display = ""
  Dim positiveValue As Boolean


  For Each Item In range_data
    If Item.Value = "O" Then
       positiveValue = True
    End If
  Next
  If positiveValue = True Then
    For Each Item In range_data
        If Item.Value <> "O" Then
             Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Item.Row, Item.Column).Value = "X"
        End If
    Next
  End If
  'positive = range_data
  'positive = display
End Sub

Sub MAIN()

  positive Range("A1:C4")

End Sub
```

Comment: Ah I was missing the "positive Range("A1:C4")". thanks I see it working now!

Answer (score 0):

The function can work if called from a `Sub`:

```
Function positive(range_data As Range)
Dim display As String
    display = ""
Dim positiveValue As Boolean


For Each Item In range_data
    If Item.Value = "O" Then
       positiveValue = True
    End If
Next
If positiveValue = True Then
    For Each Item In range_data
        If Item.Value = "" Then
             Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Item.Row, Item.Column).Value = "X"
        End If
    Next
End If

positive = "whatever"

End Function


Sub MAIN()
    x = positive(Range("M3:Q3"))
End Sub
```

But there is no reason to use a function since the function's output is not used.

Comment: Ok i think that makes sense, how would I change this to a Sub and then call it for the range of 5 cells?